# Can see apache2 "it works" site but can't connect to another site on the server

Tags: apache2

I have an ubuntu server set up on VM on my windows 10. It has apache2 set up. From my windows 10 I can connect to the server and see the apache site at 192.168.1.156 but cannot connect to another site set up on the server.

There is a torn-fac folder -> /var/www/torn-fac/index.html (+ other files). The config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName tornfac.com

    ServerAdmin iMephiles5@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/torn-fac
    ServerAlias www.tornfac.com

    <Directory /var/www>
        allow from all
        Options None
    </Directory>
    <Directory var/www/torn-fac>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I can connect to tornfac.com on the server itself but cannot connect to it from my windows 10. Anything I have configured wrong? I'm super new to this stuff.

Thanks,
Gregor